# Python Django Graphql all possible query variant generation

Tags: python, django, graphql

Is there a known way to generate all possible query variants based on a Django Graphql based project source code?

I am evaluating a product with limited documentation and I am wondering if there is something that could help me to automate the discovery process.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Right, but it is a very specific question. It is not asking what IDE I should use, but no problem, I will alter ma question.